# An interesting indefinite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Here's an interesting integral that I'm struggling with.

$$ \int \frac{x\ dx}{\sqrt{x^4 + 4x^3 - 6x^2 + 4x + 1}} $$

MY EFFORTS:
I'm very very close in reaching a closed form.

\begin{align}
&= \frac12\int \frac{2\ dx}{\sqrt{\left(x^2+\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right) + 4\left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)-6}} \\
&= \frac12\int \frac{\left(1 - \dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)\ dx}{\sqrt{\left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^2 + 4\left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)-8}} + \frac12\int \frac{\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)\ dx}{\sqrt{\left(x-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^2 + 4\sqrt{\left(x-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^2+4}-4}} \\
&= \frac12 \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{u^2+4u-8}} + \underbrace{\frac12 \int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2 + 4\sqrt{t^2+4}-4}}}_{\text{How to solve this?}}
\end{align}

As you all can see, I'm able to break integral by 2 parts and I'm struck in evaluating 2nd part. The first part can easily be solved by completing the square and trigonometric substitutions.

NOTE: In my effort pic. the variable of integration is x and should not be confused with letter n.

([1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2Vhu.jpg)

Comment: Why the downvote? I've thinking to solve this integral for hours! Finally I'm just one step away from solving it. :(

Comment: This integral leads to an elliptic one.

Comment: What's an elliptical one integral? I'm sorry but I'm not much fimiliar with advanced maths. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @ShivanshJ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral

Comment: You were downvoted because the question shows a lack of formatting. I've edited it for you, but for future reference [here is a quick tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I think the downvote is because you included a photograph. Anyway, nowadays there is computer software that can compute integrals. You should always give them a go. Such software tells me there is no hope of finding a simple expression for your problem. Not all apparently simple integrals are really simple

Comment: Sadly, [thedude is right](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fsqrt(t%5E2-4%2B4*sqrt(t%5E2%2B4))).

Comment: I've tried in many softwares but it shows error. Moreover I've observed that these softwares lack human intuition which is VERY VERY necessary for the art of integration. As for formatting I'm sorry I've very hastly posted this question for quick answer as I was frustrated that even after soo much thinking I was not getting a closed form.

Comment: @J.G. Oh no! If it's an elliptical integral that means no closed form exist?

Comment: I've read a little about elliptical integral from Wiki page that you send.

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Can you please show how did you reach your conclusion about elliptical integral?

Comment: Can someone show the relation of this integral with elliptical one?

Comment: I bet that the integral is ;$$ \int \frac{x\ dx}{\sqrt{x^4 + 4x^3 +6x^2 + 4x + 1}} $$

Comment: @JJacquelin You may be correct. Perfect square makes it very easy to evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that your effort leads to a simpler integral that the original one. They are two radicals in your last integral. This makes it more difficult to integrate. So, you are not close to solve it.

HINT :

$$x^4+4x^3-6x^2+x^4+1= (x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)(x-r_4)$$
$r_1=\frac12\left(1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{7-4\sqrt{2}} \right)$

$r_2=\frac12\left(1-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{7-4\sqrt{2}} \right)$

$r_3=\frac12\left(1+\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{7-4\sqrt{2}} \right)$

$r_4=\frac12\left(1-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{7-4\sqrt{2}} \right)$

$$I= \int \frac{x\ dx}{\sqrt{x^4 + 4x^3 - 6x^2 + 4x + 1}} $$
It is easier to integrate on this form :
$$I= \int \frac{x\ dx}{\sqrt{(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)(x-r_4)}} $$
The result involves an elliptic integral as a term of a complicated formula. From WolframAlpha :

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fsqrt((x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)(x-r_4))

NOTE :

If the integral comes from an academic exercise, there is probably a typo in it, because solving it requires an hight level of knowledge of special functions. I will not loose time with a problem suspected of mistake in the wording.

Please check your calculus which leads to the integral. Eventually edit the original version of the problem in your question.

Comment: You are right, it was a question given in academic exercise. But I don't know if it's really a typo or not because my instructor said that worksheet has tough questions of integration. Is the high level question fits for a 12th grader?

Comment: Oh! But I'm pretty sad that all my process of 'solving' this problem was in vain. :( I wish I knew about special functions.

Comment: @JJacquelin Just because WolframAlpha does not have an elementary closed antiderivative does not mean one does not exist, or that the original question contains a typo.  A very simple example of an integrand for which WolframAlpha (and *Mathematica*)  fails to compute an elementary closed form antiderivative is $$\int \frac{1-x^4}{(1+x^2+x^4)\sqrt{1 + x^4}} \, dx = \tan^{-1} \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^4}} + C.$$

Comment: @heropup. My comment is not based on the WolframAlpha result (which I show for information only). It is based on the expressions of the roots $r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4$ which seems to not allow simplification.

Comment: @Shivansh. Edit the original wording of your exercise into your question. (use the "edit" button.